# close previous opened div if a div is already opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Will try to explain what i mean :)

I have two hidden divs that opens with jquery, they both works quite good... when I'm using them separated... But if I open the div when the other one is open, the first one keeps being open in the background... I would like that one to close.

Is there an if else function i can use ?

This is what i have so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".contactDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide_contact").show();

    $('.show_hide_contact').click(function(){
    $(".contactDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".loginDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide_login").show();

    $('.show_hide_login').click(function(){
    $(".loginDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

I have created a jsfiddle to show some more.

http://jsfiddle.net/h2Hfg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just slide the other div too:

```
$('.show_hide_contact').click(function() {
    $(".contactDiv").slideToggle();
    $(".loginDiv").slideUp();
});

$('.show_hide_login').click(function(){
    $(".loginDiv").slideToggle();
    $(".contactDiv").slideUp();
});
```

Very nice of you to include the `jsFiddle` :)

Comment: Well, the problem is that i want to close the previous opened div... not open both of them.

Comment: There, sry, got out of sync with the fiddle I was playing with

Comment: You might want to include your own fiddle of this in action, because it isn't working for me...

Comment: Hey, it actually helped me :) I just added hide instead of slideUp.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't it work with `slideUp` as well as with `hide`? I'm confused :( or is the visual effect undesired?

Comment: @uʍop ǝpısdn 
Hey i tried slide up on my server, and it worked fine. the js-fiddle didnt run it.
Im voting your answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is a function exactly that does that but you can do it manually.  [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/XRmf3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $(".contactDiv").hide();
    $(".loginDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide_contact").show();
     $(".show_hide_login").show();

    $('.show_hide_contact').click(function(){
        $(".loginDiv").hide();
        $(".contactDiv").slideToggle();
    });

    $('.show_hide_login').click(function(){
        $(".contactDiv").hide();
        $(".loginDiv").slideToggle();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to.

I just added the hide function to the divs.

```
$('.show_hide_contact').click(function(){
$(".contactDiv").slideToggle();
    $(".loginDiv").hide(); /* there is hiding prev opened tag*/
});
```